# Is it possible to create a WordPress polling daemon as a part of a WP plugin?

Tags: php, windows-services, wordpress, daemon

A .Net developer, I have not yet done any WordPress plugin development, and would like some basic details/starting points for the following.

As a part of a WordPress plugin, is it possible to create a polling daemon to kick off an intermittent process (say, every two hours) - it could really do anything like database look-ups.

The functionality would be similar to a Windows service that operates in the same matter.

Is it possible to create this functionality as a part of a plugin, or would this require some server-side implementation?

Thanks.

**-- UPDATE --**

In researching the [wp_schedule_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) I see that it is an event executed whenever someone visits your site.  However, for sites with little traffic, this may not be optimal, but a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. But that would also require WP to have cron-access to the server. The cron-job would work on the intervals on your plugin's script. Similar solution is in the tutorials at [nettuts.com](http://nettuts.com) on WP plugin development.

Comment: So would there be implementation issues for widespread public deployment?

Comment: Nope, usually servers running Wordpress have the cron/services to be settable. Will you be hosting on *nix servers or windows?

Comment: It could be either, as I would have no control on the server environment where someone installs the plugin.  See my update above.

Comment: Yeah plugins like that has the functionality you are looking for. But you need to work on the cron-event, not the visit event.

Comment: Just looked at it. It also has the hourly event setter. So, dependency over the cron is eliminated.

Comment: Yeah, but that only executes if a page has been visited and the required time has elapsed.  There could also be other reasons for it to fail: http://wpdailybits.com/blog/replace-wordpress-cron-with-real-cron-job/74

Comment: Exactly, if you need it to work independent and periodically you'd need real cron/service.

Comment: Alright, so back to the original question, I suppose - if I need real cron/service capability, is it achievable by way of a WordPress plugin.  Or put a different way, is it feasible to create a cron job/service on a server during a WP plugin installation on a shared server? I'm guessing hosting companies may not allow this, but some hosting packages do provide cron accessibility.

Comment: Yes possible. Most hosting provides the cron access. And the link you shared above has the necessary information on how to setup such real cron.